# Retrieve Entries from Google Calendar

Tags: c#, calendar, google-calendar-api, gdata, gdata-api

I'm working on a function that retrieves Events from a google calendar. I have implemented it according the tutorial found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_dotnet?csw=1)
The function does work but only retrieves a maximum of 25 events and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

That's my function

```
void retrieveEvents() 
{
    EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService("MyTest");
    service.setUserCredentials("email", "password");
    service.QueryClientLoginToken();

    query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/USER-ID/private/full");

    query.StartTime = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
    query.EndTime = DateTime.Now;

    EventFeed calfeed = service.Query(query);

    foreach (EventEntry ee in calfeed.Entries) 
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(ee.Title.Text + "\r\n");
        listEvents.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, v2 is deprecated. You really should move your code up to using v3 of the API.

From the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/faq#retrieve_more):

**How do I retrieve more than 25 results in an event feed?**

You can use the query parameter max-results to retrieve more than the default 25. If you wish to retrieve all of the events in a feed, set the max-results parameter to a really large number. You can also page through events by taking advantage of the next links, available as child elements of a feed.